# Replace HTTP response header status from curl output

Tags: regex, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, mod-perl

Is there a way to replace the `HTTP/1.1 200` status with `HTTP/1.1 500` status after getting the response from the curl command?

If the body of the response contains the string `Error retrieving data` then the status will ordinarily be `HTTP/1.1 200`. I need to change it to `HTTP/1.1 500` (internal server error)

For example

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $curlvalue = `curl -vk http://myserver.com/test.html`;
$search_string = "Error retrieving data";

if ( $curlvalue =~ m/$search_string/isg ) {
  print $curlvalue;
  print "AFTER OUTPUT\n";
  $value =~ s/HTTP\/1.1 200/HTTP\/1.1 500/g;
}

print $curlvalue;
```

**output**

```
perl test.pl**

** About to connect() to myserver.com (#0)
*   Trying 111.111.111.11... connected
* Connected to myserver.comt (11.111.111.11) port 80 (#0)
> GET /iis/mybroker/test.html HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.19.7 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.19.7 NSS/3.19.1     Basic ECC zlib/1.2.3 libidn/1.18 libssh2/1.4.2
> Host: myserver.com
> Accept: */*
> 
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--     0   
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Mon, 16 Jan 2017 13:47:10 GMT
< Server: Apache
< X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
< 
{ [data not shown]
105   315    0   315    0     0    155      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--   155*      Connection #0 to host myserver.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error retrieving data (1000)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Error retrieving data (1000)</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>*
```

*AFTER OUTPUT MESSAGE not showing HTTP header details*

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error retrieving data (1000)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Error retrieving data (1000)</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: If you are simply fetching a web resource then you would be better off using one of Perl's libraries such as `LWP` to do this instead of shelling out to run `curl`. Presumably you're doing it this way in an attempt to stay in your comfort zone? Why do you have the **insecure** option `-k` enabled?

Answer (score 0):

You've not answered the comments for four hours now, so here's a wild guess

This is your program

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $curlvalue = `curl -vk http://myserver.com/test.html`;

$search_string = "Error retrieving data";

if ( $curlvalue =~ m/$search_string/isg ) {
  print $curlvalue;
  print "AFTER OUTPUT\n";
  $value =~ s/HTTP\/1.1 200/HTTP\/1.1 500/g;
}

print $curlvalue;
```

It has neither `use strict` nor `use warnings 'all'` at the top, which are essential for any Perl program, and especially if you are asking for help with it.

My wild guess is that you're expecting the full output of `curl`, and you're trying to write a *filter* that will amend the reported status in specific cases. Is that right?

If so, then the problem is your substitution line

```
$value =~ s/HTTP\/1.1 200/HTTP\/1.1 500/g;
```

Because there is no `$value` variable, this line has no effect. You probably want `$curlvalue`, and I would use a different delimiter to avoid all of those escapes

There's also no need for the `/g` modifier, nor various other stuff, so I think your code should look like this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $curlvalue = `curl -v http://myserver.com/test.html`;

my $search = "Error retrieving data";

if ( $curlvalue =~ /$search/i ) {

    print "BEFORE CHANGES\n";
    print $curlvalue;

    $curlvalue =~ s|HTTP/1.1 200|HTTP/1.1 500|;
}

print "AFTER CHANGES\n";
print $curlvalue;
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use cURL; there are Perl modules based on [`LWP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP).

In your example you try to match a string and then replace the status code from `200` to `500` if the string matched. HTML should not ever be matched with regular expressions. Instead you should use a DOM parser which can also handle nested tags easily.

According to the RFC, `HTTP 200` is only for successful requests, so the API does not meet the standard.

You could do it with the following code:

#### template.html

```html
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Error retrieving data (1000)</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<H1>Error retrieving data (1000)</H1>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**Perl code**

```perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use Mojo::UserAgent;

use feature 'say';

my $ua = Mojo::UserAgent->new;
my $response = $ua->get("http://myserver.com/iis/mybroker/test.html")->res->dom->at('h1')->text;
say $response eq "Error retrieving data (1000)" ? "Status code should be 500" : "Status code 200 is correct";
```

Comment: *"You should not use cURL"* I think you should substantiate that. Why shouldn't the OP use `curl`?